# what is the correct file path in eclipse spring

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, filenotfoundexception

I am working on an introduction to spring course, but I have an issue with my `SpringConfig.xml` file path. As show on the picture, I just added it everywhere as a hailmary but that's not working either:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [SpringConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [SpringConfig] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

My path:

[image]

Main method code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringConfig");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please don't forget to add the file extension **".xml"**, spring will read it from **src/main/resource**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringConfig.xml");


}
```